# How to automate django deployment?

Tags: django, deployment, devops, fabric

OK, I am desperate enough to finally post a github question. 
SUMMARY:
Django deploy -> digital ocean droplet -> nginx and gunicord + git pull

It works, but manually writing all the commands is way to tedious + error prone. I have been trying to find a suitable tool ever since, and kinda need some advice.

SOO FAR:
I have tried [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/), BUUUT complexity and simplicity baffles me. Some tutorial are way to trivial, some are way too complex and 95 % of them seems to be outdated(this seems relevant in this case , because syntax has changed drastically)
In addition, the most basic example in docs don't work no matter how many times I have tried to correct it(ssh connection vie password).
P.S. I am completely new to devops, so a lot of things is confusing for me

Beside that, I have tried to dive into some other tools like bash scripting and ansible and dropped them shortly after, mainly due to them not being as alluring as Fabric seems to be.

My question is!
Should  I continue tring to solve Fabric, or is there some other commonly used way to make deployment a simple and enjoyable matter while preserving the functionality?
::btw I am windows 10 user put prefer to use git bash, could this be the problem for Fabric(it seemed not being able to recognize ls command and I used DIR instead)

Comment: Are you able to use jenkins, https://buddy.works or github actions?

Answer (score 0):

I typically recommend using ansible over fabric unless you are working with *nix.  If you have to work with AIX, Solaris, HPUX, fabric can offer you more flexibility since you don't need python on the server.  It will take about two-days to get up to speed on ansible, but if you're already using django, jinja2 (the templating language used by anible) should be a snap.